# Can't program Arduino from OS X

Tags: ubuntu, osx-lion, arduino

I am trying to program an Arduino from OS X Lion.  It absolutely won't work and I have no other machines to work this on.

Here is the error I get when I try to upload:

```
Binary sketch size: 1260 bytes (of a 32256 byte maximum)
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

I tried up wipe and reinstall the arduino dev kit and I get the same bad results.

I also tried to program this on VMWare Fusion running ubuntu.  I get the same `programmer not responding error`.  I also watched my `/var/log/syslog` during this process and saw the following error:  `io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1`  I have no idea what to make of this.

I don't think its a bad board.  I have the same problem with 2 arduinos:  a brand new arduino out of the box and another that is 3 weeks old.  This used to work but suddenly failed.

Any low level CLI tools that I can test and verify what USB port I am using?

How can I make this arduino accept my program?

Comment: Did you check the obvious things, like selecting the correct board and serial port in the Tools menu?

Comment: The board is an Uno and is selected in the tools menu.  When I plug in the Arduino two options appear in my Tools > Serial Port menu: `/dev/tty.usbmodemfd121` and `/dev/cu.usbmodemfd121`.  I get error described above irrespective of which option I choose.

Comment: In terms of low level tools, the problem is that you can try to connect directly to the serial port, but most likely it’s not programmed to respond to you. You could try to see if avrdude will talk to it directly: `/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -p m328p -b 115200 -c arduino -P /dev/cu.usbmodemfd121 -v` (assuming you installed Arduino in `/Applications` as usual). That should report the device signature and might give you more information if something is wrong. If that command succeeds, there is something weird wrong with the Arduino GUI.

Comment: Something happened and it worked for one upload.   And now it won't work again.  new error is `avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x4c`  This whole Arduino programming environment seems very unstable.

Comment: Now its really terrible!  I found a work around that requires both arduinos.  I can upload to arduino A.  Only once.  If I try to upload twice I get `avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00`.  Then I have to swap to Arduino B which allows me only one upload. The pattern repeats with the second arduino.  Is there a way to tell the Arduino to get in sync?  Or force it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have a MAC and something similar happened to me... I solved it by creating the folder /var/tmp

You can do that in terminal typing:

`sudo mkdir /var/tmp`

maybe you will need to give to it full perms.

`sudo chmod 777 /var/tmp`

but Im not shure about this step.

It worked to me because the arduino program tryes to write the temp files to this folder and, if the folder doesnt exist, the program assumes that some problem is happening with the programmer.

Maybe it will work to you, maybe not... we will see!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem...
I've enabled verbose mode and got something like:

```
Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbserial-A6013O93
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200    
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -carduino -P/dev/cu.usbserial-A6013O93 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:/var/folders/d6/nx58qfsj6zbbw65bcsrnxc4r0000gn/T/build6866034938793144439.tmp/Blink.cpp.hex:i
```

changed baud rate to 57600 (the **-b11520** to **-b57600**):

```
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -carduino -P/dev/cu.usbserial-A6013O93 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:/var/folders/d6/nx58qfsj6zbbw65bcsrnxc4r0000gn/T/build6866034938793144439.tmp/Blink.cpp.hex:i
```

And it worked. Program uploaded. 
Hope it helps.